# What causes this behavior when defining a function named ':'

Tags: zsh

If I create the following function

```
function :() {
  echo "hi"
}
```

then any time I type any character, the function is executed *as soon as I type it, and before I hit <kbd>return</kbd>!*

This seems to be somehow caused by something in my `.zshrc`, since it does *not* happen if I start Z shell with `zsh -f`, and it doesn't happen in Bash.

How can I figure out what is causing this weird behavior?

Comment: `How can I figure out what is causing this weird behavior?` -- execute `set -x`

Comment: Where at you defining this function? in your `.zshrc` or at a zsh prompt? `:` in bourne shells `:` is the nop operator. in zsh `:`  is a builtin documented in `man zshbuiltins`

Comment: @the_velour_fog: at the prompt.  thanks for the tip—I'll look it up in the `zshbuiltins` man page!

Answer (score 2):

The builtin `:` does nothing (it's a [no-op](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP)). It's used in many places in zsh's completion code, amongst others. It may well be used in some code related to key bindings. If you override it with a function, expect your function to be called a lot.

Overriding standard command names with something completely different is a bad idea. But if you really want to define your own `:`, make it an alias (to a function with a longer, explicit name). That way it won't affect autoloaded functions (except functions autoloaded explicitly with `autoload` without the `-U` option — so whenever you use `autoload`, pass `-U`), including completion code.